# Will my Nvidia 7900GS support 2560x1440 in 2D?

Tags: graphics-card, display

I'm buying a new monitor with a resolution of 2560x1440.  Will my existing graphics card, an Nvidia 7900GS, support this resolution for 2D work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should. The max resolution of the 7900GS is 2560 x 1600. You need to be sure that you are using a dual-link DVI cable, as the maximum resolution supported by single-link DVI is 1920x1200.

Source: http://www.newegg.com/product/product.aspx?Item=N82E16814130056